# WPF DataGrid Bind Radiobutton Column to Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I've been looking for a while, but I can't seem to find why my datagrid radiobutton column (which is generating) isn't working properly. I can click on the radio buttons, but they don't change. For some background I'm making a real estate management program and this window is the "Edit Property" page. I'm creating a datagrid where the user can select the tenants that have lived in that property as well as the current (or latest) tenant.

Here is my xaml for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="375" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentProperty.tennants}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Lived Here" Binding="{Binding something}"/> <!-- I'm still working on this. This is a totally different problem. I know how to bind. -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Current">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" GroupName="current" IsChecked="{Binding current, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

At the moment, there are 5 tenants that show up in the datagrid (which is what I want) and one of them has the current radiobutton selected (which is what I want). I can't, however select a different radiobutton. It just deselects the current one until I click on it again.

Thanks. I've been going crazy about this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

@Ethan, when you have a problem with your .NET program, your very first step should be to go to a search engine and to type `A B`, where `A` is the name of the UI element and `B` is the name of the type of member that it is. In your case, you'd need to search for [`DataGridCheckBoxColumn class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Had you done this, you'd have found out what your problem was straight away... here's your `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Lived Here"/>
```

Here's the one from the example in the linked page:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Online Order?" IsThreeState="True" Binding="{Binding 
    OnlineOrderFlag}" />
```

Straight away, we can see that you have not set the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding` property. If we look at the properties on the page, we can see that the `Binding` property

> Gets or sets the binding that associates the column with a property in the data source.

So, you have not connected your `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` with any property from the data bound item, as you did with your other column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
```

After setting an appropriate `Binding` on the column, you *should* see that it all works as expected.

---

As can be seen clearly from the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127525/wpf-datagrid-bind-radiobutton-column-to-property) page of the Help Center, you should search thoroughly *before* posting questions here to prevent easily solvable questions from being posted. Please do so in future.

---

UPDATE >>>

@Ethan, I misread your question and accept that you *may* have indeed done some research and for that, I apologise. However, I wonder if you could possibly outline the part in my answer that describes how stupid you are? As one of the [site moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators), it is my duty to explain how this website works to new and junior members.

This helpful advice is normally welcomed and thanked for by most users, so I don't really understand why you have taken such a negative view... after all, I'm the *only* one to have bothered to *try* to answer your question in the first place.

Regarding your last comment, don't edit your question for me... edit it for yourself... the better your question is, the more attention it will receive.

If you've now calmed down, maybe I can address your *actual* question? I have copied your XAML into a new project with some dummy data and I'm afraid to say that there is *no* problem with that code. Your problem must lie elsewhere, perhaps in a property setter that changes the data, or something like that.

Now, I'm going to attempt to give you a bit more advice here, but this in no way means that I think that you are stupid... when you add a question here and provide code, it is advisable to ensure that your code example *actually* demonstrates your problem. I often used to find that when simplifying a problem to describe in a question here, that I'd find the solution during that process.

Comment: I did. I don't want a check box. I want a radio button. Please read the question properly before posting an answer describing how stupid I am for not doing research. Please do so in the future. Thank you.

Comment: The question is about the Template Radio Button Column. Not this: `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Lived Here"/>`. I know that's not complete. I'll edit the question for your benefit though.

Comment: Sorry about how crappy of a comment those were last year. I just came back to this question cause it's had 1000+ views. I must have been in a really really bad mood. Thanks for the help you offered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a data-trigger for your data template -

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers> 
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="current" Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
 </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

PS : This is just a work around.